# Why the for loop ends up at dna[2]"

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof

I've been working on java programming developed to find the gene in DNA strands. My question is why the for loop ends up at dna[2] and the output is stuck at the third String and no more results are returned. The following is the code:

```
import edu.duke.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Part1 {
        public String findSimpleGene (String dna) {
            String result = "";
            int startIndex = dna.indexOf("atg");
            int stopIndex = dna.indexOf("taa", startIndex+3);
            result = dna.substring(startIndex, stopIndex+3);
            if (startIndex != -1 
            && stopIndex != -1 
            && (stopIndex - startIndex) % 3 ==0) {
                return result;
            }
            else {
                return "Not Exist";
            }
            
        }
        public void testSimpleGene () {
            String dna[] = new String[5];
            dna[0] = "cccatggggtaaaaatgataataggagagagagagagagttt";
            dna[1] = "ccatggggtctaaataataa";
            dna[2] = "atggggcgtaaagaataa";
            dna[3] = "acggggtttgaagaatgaaccaat";
            dna[4] = "acggggtttgaagaatgaaccaataacga";
            for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            String result = findSimpleGene(dna[i]);
            System.out.println("DNA strand:" + dna[i]);
            System.out.println("Gene:" + result);
        }
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: `System.out.println()` the value of `stopIndex`.

Comment: Your code is "stuck" because an exception (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException) occurs. Please also state this in the description of your question.

Answer (score 0):

For `dna[3] = "acggggtttgaagaatgaaccaat"` 
**startIndex is 14 and stopIndex is -1** since there is no "taa"
After that you are finding **subString(14,2)** which will throw below exception in this case.
Method threw **'java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException'** exception

Answer (score 0):

For

```
dna[3] = "acggggtttgaagaatgaaccaat";
```

Your code is throwing `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception & hence you sees it is no longer advancing to next iteration of for loop :

```
int startIndex = dna.indexOf("atg"); // gives 14
int stopIndex = dna.indexOf("taa", startIndex + 3); // gives -1
result = dna.substring(startIndex, stopIndex + 3); //throws `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because startIndex is larger than stopIndex.
```

To avoid this kind of scenario, you can check startIndex is always less than stopIndex before calling substring:

```
if(startIndex < stopIndex && startIndex!=-1 &&  stopIndex < dna.length()){
 result = dna.substring(startIndex, stopIndex + 3);
 ..}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the way you've written your `findSimpleGene` method, specifically when you try to retrieve `stopIndex`. In fact, in that context `startIndex` could be at the end of the string or less than 3 characters before the end, so when you're performing `dna.indexOf("taa", startIndex + 3)` you might be exceeding the length of the given `String`. Also, computing `stopIndex` when `startIndex` could be -1 makes little sense.

You could add a check before the computation, like a ternary operator, which controls that `startIndex` is not -1 and accounting 3 to it still makes it within the given `String`. On a side note, just to reduce your code, you could already set `result` to "Not Exist" and update it only if the substring can take place (less if-else branching and better readability).

```
public String findSimpleGene(String dna) {
    String result = "Not Exist";
    int startIndex = dna.indexOf("atg");
    int stopIndex = startIndex >= 0 && startIndex + 3 < dna.length() ? dna.indexOf("taa", startIndex + 3) : -1;

    if (startIndex != -1 && stopIndex != -1 && (stopIndex - startIndex) % 3 == 0) {
        result = dna.substring(startIndex, stopIndex + 3);
    }

    return result;
}
```

##### Output

```
DNA strand:cccatggggtaaaaatgataataggagagagagagagagttt
Gene:atggggtaa
DNA strand:ccatggggtctaaataataa
Gene:Not Exist
DNA strand:atggggcgtaaagaataa
Gene:Not Exist
DNA strand:acggggtttgaagaatgaaccaat
Gene:Not Exist
DNA strand:acggggtttgaagaatgaaccaataacga
Gene:atgaaccaataa
```

Here is also a link to test the code above:

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/s7F